# org.apache.jasper.JasperException:File "/struts-jquery-tags" not found

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I am getting the above exception when accessing my application. Have checked the different posts in Stack Overflow.

As mentioned in the solutions i am using
    **<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>**
Instead of 
    **<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts2-jquery-tags" %>**
for the struts2-jquery plugin

But even then i am facing the same error, can anyone please help me out.

Comment: What version of S2? What version of S2 jQuery plugin? How are you including the library (pom.xml, in WEB-INF/lib, etc.)?

Comment: Struts2(Version - 2.5.16). Struts2 jQuery plugin(Version - 3.7.1) and I am including these in my pom.xml

Comment: If nothing else I'd suggest trying the right version of the plug-in first. Look at the GitHub page and at the very least do what it says.

Comment: Tried that as well but no luck..Can anyone please help me out in this

Comment: You're using the wrong version of the plug-in.